# Getting buttonbackground image from dynamically added button

Tags: c#, button

I am populating a form with buttons based on the amount of images in my resources of my application.

I am looping through the images in the resources and foreach image create a button and then set the backgroundimage to the picture.

Now i need to get the image of the button i clicked and pass it to a method. How do i accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows:

```
  ResourceSet resourceSet = Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
        {
            object resource = entry.Value;
            Button b = new Button();
            b.BackgroundImage = (Image)resource;
            b.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            b.Bounds = new Rectangle(left, top, buttonSize, buttonSize);
            this.Controls.Add(b);
            left += buttonSize;
            if (left + buttonSize > this.ClientSize.Width)
            {
                left = 0;
                top += 100;
            }
            b.Click += new EventHandler(buttonClick);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

```
protected void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     Button myButton = (Button)sender;
     ImageProcessMethod(myButton.BackgroundImage);
}
```